# HTML block inputs until correct POST is send

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms

I'm trying to make word-guesser Django app. User is given 5 rows of input boxes and every input box corresponds to specific word's letter. First, user has to guess first row etc. (Game Wordle is pretty similar). And the main thing is: I want to have only first row active, then after user hits the button, post request is send, blocking first row and unlocking second one etc. Any tips, please?
Here's my html code:

```
{% block content %}
<a href="/words/get" style="margin-left: 48%">new word</a>
<div class="boxes-row" style="text-align: center;">
    {% for num in '12345' %}
    <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            {% for index in word_length %}
            <div class="word-box">

                <!-- Get row and column numbers with actual corresponding values from letters dict -->
                {% with input_name="row"|add:num|add:"_col"|add:index %}
                    {% for key, value in letters.items %}
                        {% if key == input_name %}
                            <input type="text" class="letter-input authInput" autocomplete='off' name="{{ input_name }}"
                                maxlength="1" value="{{ value.upper }}" oninput="jumpToNextInput(this)" />
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endwith %}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 1rem;">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

I tried various JS functions, but i'm not really into this language at the moment.

Comment: you could split it into three parts. First display all the things that were already guessed, then display the input field and below display the number of rows that are remaining. 
after each post you update the already guessed and remaining rows